# sqlserver backup using c# getting issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I want to create backup of particular database using **C#** code, and for that I am using following code.

**Code**

```
       Console.WriteLine("Backup manager");

        Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();

        bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;

        bkpDBFull.Database = "SampleDB";

        bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\Temp\Back\fulBak.bak", DeviceType.File);
        bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Database backup";
        bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "Code backup";
        bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;

        bkpDBFull.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
        bkpDBFull.Complete += Backup_Completed;

        Server MyServer = new Server("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;User ID=user;Password=pass");

        bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(MyServer);
```

and the two event's are following.

**CompletionStatusInPercent**

```
    private static void CompletionStatusInPercent(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", args.Percent);
    }
```

**Backup_Completed**

```
    private static void Backup_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hurray...Backup completed.");
        Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
    }
```

In the entire code it getting a only one problem in below code

**Problem code**

```
        Server MyServer = new Server("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;User ID=user;Password=pass");
```

I think I had put name of sqlserver in wrong way.

I need a solution of how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up the constructors. The argument for new Server, is either the name of the server (string), or an instance of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection`
class in the smo name space. It's constructor takes a connectionstring as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As here, Tony Hopkinson I had made more research and come up with a solution...

I just simple remove my **Problematic code** with following code...

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=.");
        ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection(con);
        Server MyServer = new Server(sc);
```

So, I hope this will be useful to many other...